# List partitioning in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a table with following schema:

MyTable {
User_ID,
Task_ID,
Task_Description
}
where Task_ID is the primary key.

I wish to partition it on User_ID. Also, new users may be added and I want new corresponding partitions to get created automatically. 
I went through [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/partitioning/twp-partitioning-11gr2-2009-09-130569.pdf) (see page-8) and found that Oracle 11g provides Interval partitioning which does similar thing but with intervals.

Can I do the same with User_ID?

Comment: How many distinct values of `user_id` are there?  What data type?  If `user_id` is a numeric key, you could create an interval partitioned table based on ranges of `user_id` values.  If it is a character key, based on the fact that `user_id` seems like something that would have many possible values, it would seem likely that you really want to hash partition the table if you want to partition on `user_id`.

Comment: user_id is varchar(128) with expected values not to exceed 1000 in near future. I want every partition to have only 1 user_id so hashing doesn't seem necessary. Still, I am ready to define hash for it if provides me with the required feature. Does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't automatically generate a unique partition for each distinct `varchar(128)` value.

You could hash partition the table.  That would not guarantee that every partition had a single, unique `user_id` value.  It would ensure that all the rows with the same `user_id` were in a single partition and would eliminate the need to do manual partition maintenance.

You could list partition the table.  That would require, though, that you explicitly add a new partition when a new `user_id` value is added.

If the `user_id` values were strictly predictable, you could probably do something with an interval partitioning scheme on a virtual column.  But that seems highly unlikely to be practical.

What is the business problem that you are trying to solve?  Why is it necessary to have a single `user_id` value in each partition?  Why are you partitioning the table in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for replying Justin. The reason I wish to partition on `user_ID` is that we don’t want the performance for 1 user to be affected in any way because of a large volume of data of another user. We were at one point thinking of creating separate table for each user but then thought that partitioning would help us achieve the same, given we have the same schema for all the users.

Comment: @Raghav - One user will be impacted by other users storing large amounts of data regardless of the partitioning scheme if only because those user's activity will generally push light users' blocks out of the buffer cache forcing more physical I/O on those users.  Are you saying that all the access on this table is going to involve full partition scans based on the `user_id`?  Nothing will use the primary key?  Most access won't involve another index?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: Every query on the table will have `user_id`. 
`task_id` was kept as primary key but I could very well keep `user_id, task_id` as the primary key of the table.
I can have an index on `user_id` but wouldn't partitioning be a better approach? I take your point that even after partitioning, user activity may be a spoiler. In that case, what do you suggest?